# Accessing android SD card folder through iPhone/iPad?

Tags: iphone, android, ios, ipad, networking

I am hoping to use my android phone as a portable hotspot, connect my iPad to it and access pictures etc on it. I know android can make folders accessible on a network, I just wondered if the iPad can access these folders?

Also, I would like to be able to make an app that can access these, so if it possible, can someone point me towards some samples/tutorials/resources etc please? Fairly new to the iOS platform and working my way through various tutorials.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Android supports to create WiFi Hotspot for sharing Internet.
It may not support File Transfer in between.